# How do I get an Icon on a .jar file?

Tags: java, jar, icons, exe, executable-jar

I have written a program in java, and I am able to execute it as a jar file. I was wondering two things. one, how would I make the .jar file have a desktop icon other than the standard java icon. and two, I am using netbeans, how would I create a .exe file instead of a .jar file?

Comment: You should probably tell us what platform you're on, although I guess it is clear from your question that it's windows.

Comment: that would be correct. it is windows.  (7 to be exact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Kitsune said, you can make an executable file. The Java packager I'm most familiar with is [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). It's highly configurable and can be called from Ant scripts, so it can easily integrate into an existing Ant-based build process.

Answer (score 2):

If your app. has a GUI and can be distributed from a server, look into [Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml).

JWS:

- Is cross platform.
- Can provide icons for desktop shortcuts and menu items.
- Provides the [IntegrationService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/index.html) that allows the user to choose what shortcuts they want.
- Is supported by Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You don't If you want an exe with an icon to auto-launch a jar file for you, take a look at WinRun4j.