# Change icon of executable exe file

Tags: java, netbeans, icons, exe

I have created an executable file using NetBeans 8.0.2 (the standard JDK), following the instructions on this website about native packaging: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html.

Now, how do I change the icon of the exe installer file from the standard Java coffee cup, to my own custom icon? (I was able to change the icon that displays in the installed application's top left window, by directly coding the frame's image resource in the source code of my application).

However I want my custom icon to also be displayed on the actual exe installer file, and the installed application's desktop icon. I had the same issue when I tried an MSI file, instead of and EXE file. I tried searching for other solutions, but none of them have worked for me. I even tried Resource Hacker, but that didn't work for me. How do other people achieve this (seemingly simple/straightforward) thing? I would imagine this requirement is in high demand.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209812/how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882043/how-do-i-get-an-icon-on-a-jar-file?rq=1) can help. Both are SO answers to similar questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Icon for executable Jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19927509/set-icon-for-executable-jar-file)

Comment: You need some packaging tool to make executable like InstallBuilder or Install4J

Comment: Hi, some of these suggestions were only to change the icon of the open application, not the actual icon of the executable file, or the desktop file before it is opened by the user. However, I found the sure-fire solution that worked for me, and was easy enough to do entirely from their GUI option without any complex code, was the InstallBuilder (the free evaluation download).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after looking at a quick video demo of InstallBuilder:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wMXWq2b5IxM
I think this is the easiest solution for customising (plus it offers a whole help of features). It looks like a high-end product. HOWEVER, it is pricey - starting at around $500, but they do have a free evaluation download, so I'll start there. There are some other free tools out there, but InstallBuilder seems to be the most user-friendly I've seen so far.

Comment: I am able to use an academic version of InstallBuilder, as a student, on a recurring 30-day period on the evaluation product - THANK YOU!